# Tool to select closed region in figure

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot

I have generated data where I want to select specific region of the data such that I can run conditional removal to that region and elsewhere greedy removal.

I know that there is some tools for FEM to make meshes, but not sure if there are such structures for drawing closed areas.

Is there any tool in MATLAB to draw closed areas where to apply the conditional algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll find [`impoly`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impoly.html) useful. It also has an option `'Closed'` that allows you to draw closed polygons.